# How to maintain the original currency when I import data into Salesforce?

Tags: multi-currency

in my company we have integrated Salesforce with Callidus CPQ for quote creation. Actually when I create a quote with CPQ and import (automatically) it into Salesforce, the currency that appears in Salesforce is the default user currency and not the original one. It is possible to maintain the original currency when I import currency values into Salesforce?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not familiar with the Callidus CPQ solution, what you describe is the default behaviour in a multi-currency organisation if you have not specified a value in the [CurrencyIsoCode](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_objects_fequently_occurring_fields.htm#i1436782) field. Is it possible to configure the integration to map the original currency into the Salesforce [CurrencyIsoCode](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_objects_fequently_occurring_fields.htm#i1436782) field?

> **CurrencyIsoCode**. For organizations that have multicurrency enabled, the CurrencyIsoCode field contains the string representation of the currency ISO code associated with currency values in the object. Note that the User object also has a DefaultCurrencyIsoCode field, which is the default currency for that user. For example, a user in France could have a DefaultCurrencyIsoCode set to Euros, and that would be their default currency in the application. However, the User object could have currency custom fields stored in a different currency.

If you don't have multi-currency enabled in your org, perhaps you could create some custom fields to contain this information though that may not be ideal. Enabling Multi-Currency is a one way thing in the org and Salesforce Support provide you a full check list to go through to ensure your happy with it. Its best to direct this query back to the integration vendor in my view.

Comment: Actually we have not enabled the Multi-currency feature. Is there any alternative to do that withount this feature or is it mandatory for this porpose?

Comment: I've added some further thoughts on this to the answer, thanks.

Comment: There are many, many benefits to enabling multi-currency in SFDC when you have opportunities in multiple currencies (Euros, GBP, USD, JPY, etc). For example, SFDC will do automatic conversion to corporate currency in any report that adds up opportunity amounts (or any other currency field for that matter).  You can even do dated exchange rates where the conversion rate varies over time based on the Opportunity.closeDate.